# Simple timed event template class

Tags: c++

It's a simple timed event template class. It's used in a 3D multiplayer game!

```
template <class T>
class CTimeEventDecorator : public CBaseDecorator, public CPooledObject<CTimeEventDecorator<T>>
{
public:
    typedef CTimeEvent<T> TTimeEventType;
    typedef std::vector<TTimeEventType> TTimeEventContainerType;

    CTimeEventDecorator(const TTimeEventContainerType& TimeEventContainer, T* pValue = 0)
        : it_start(TimeEventContainer.begin())
        , it_cur(TimeEventContainer.begin())
        , it_next(TimeEventContainer.begin())
        , it_end(TimeEventContainer.end())
        , pData(pValue)
    {
        if (it_start == it_end)
            *pValue = T();
        else
            ++it_next;
    }

    void SetData(T* pValue)
    {
        pData = pValue;
    }

protected:
    CTimeEventDecorator(CTimeEventDecorator<T>& ted, CParticleInstance* pFirstInstance, CParticleInstance* pInstance)
        : it_start(ted.it_start)
        , it_end(ted.it_end)
        , it_cur(ted.it_cur)
        , it_next(ted.it_next)
        , pData((T*)((unsigned char*)ted.pData - (DWORD)pFirstInstance + (DWORD)pInstance))
    {
        if (it_start == it_end)
            *pData = T();
    }

    virtual CBaseDecorator* __Clone(CParticleInstance* pFirstInstance, CParticleInstance* pInstance)
    {
        return new CTimeEventDecorator(*this, pFirstInstance, pInstance);
    }

    virtual void __Execute(const CDecoratorData& d)
    {
        if (it_start == it_end)
            Remove();
        else if (it_cur->m_fTime > d.fTime)
            *pData = it_cur->m_Value;
        else
        {
            while (it_next != it_end && it_next->m_fTime <= d.fTime)
                ++it_cur, ++it_next;

            if (it_next == it_end)
            {
                *pData = it_cur->m_Value;
                Remove();
            }
            else
            {
                float length = it_next->m_fTime - it_cur->m_fTime;

                *pData = it_cur->m_Value * (1 - (d.fTime - it_cur->m_fTime) / length) ;
                *pData += it_next->m_Value * ((d.fTime - it_cur->m_fTime) / length);
            }
        }
    }

    typename TTimeEventContainerType::const_iterator it_start;
    typename TTimeEventContainerType::const_iterator it_end;
    typename TTimeEventContainerType::const_iterator it_cur;
    typename TTimeEventContainerType::const_iterator it_next;

    T* pData;
};
```

What optimizations, refactor I can do?

Comment: Ok, what's it supposed to do? What problem does it solve? How is it called by the rest of the code?

Comment: You should check the rules on using underscore. [Rules on Underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/14065) Both `__Clone` and `__Execute` are reserved for use by the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

This answer may come across as harsh, but it is not supposed to be.

Your code looks good, BUT it lacks any comments so it’s quite difficult for other people to understand what it’s purpose is.  I have no doubt that today you know what your code does, but if you are working in a professional capacity in three months time when you have written another several thousand lines you won’t remember.

You have used base classes, but we can’t see them, this means we have even less understanding of the code.

Your coding styles are nice and clean, but you need to decide which one to use for instance you’ve got camel case and underscores in variable names.

It’s possible that things are being done in the base classes that I can’t see, but you seem to be dereferencing pointers without verifying they are not null.  See *pData, which isn’t initialised.

And a really minor thing length could be a const variable.

You say you want to optimise the code.  What problems are there with it?  Have you benchmarked it’s current performance, where is most of the time spent?

Comment: Personally I think most comments are bad (though there are exceptions). Self documenting code is better. But one or the other is required. In this case we have neither.

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

I have no idea what is happening inside the code or how it works.

@Code Gorilla has suggested comments. I would suggest writing self documenting code. Better type/method/variable names would be nice. Obtuse things should definitely be explained.

### Code Review

Typedef's are old school.

```
    typedef TimeEvent<T> TTimeEventType;
    typedef std::vector<TTimeEventType> TTimeEventContainerType;
```

The modern equivalent is a using statement.

```
    using TTimeEventType          = TimeEvent<T>;
    using TTimeEventContainerType = std::vector<TTimeEventType>;
```

---

Haveing zero (`0`) as the default value of a pointer is untidy.

```
    CTimeEventDecorator(const TTimeEventContainerType& TimeEventContainer, T* pValue = 0)
```

Use the modern `nullptr`.

```
    CTimeEventDecorator(const TTimeEventContainerType& TimeEventContainer, T* pValue = nullptr)
```

---

Pointers are dangerous. Why are we allowing a dangerous item into your class. I would wrap that in a class to protect against accidental usage.

---

Well that look particularly dangerious.

```
        , pData((T*)((unsigned char*)ted.pData - (DWORD)pFirstInstance + (DWORD)pInstance))
```

I know I don't like comments. But this absolutely needs some explaining. I have no idea what is happening here.

Also you are using `C` cast `(T*)`. Please work out what the C++ equivalent is and use that. Probably `reinterpret_cast<T*>`. That will at least let automated tools find and warn people that you are trying to crash the program.

---

Don't use pointers if you don't need to:

```
    virtual CBaseDecorator* __Clone(CParticleInstance* pFirstInstance, CParticleInstance* pInstance)
    {
        return new CTimeEventDecorator(*this, pFirstInstance, pInstance);
    }
```

You could simply return an object here. The code would work just as well.

```
    virtual CBaseDecorator __Clone(CParticleInstance* pFirstInstance, CParticleInstance* pInstance)
    {
        return CTimeEventDecorator(*this, pFirstInstance, pInstance);
    }
```

Now with no dynamic allocation.

OK. If you must use dynamic allocation (I can't tell because you don't show the base class so I can't see if this is inherited. Then at least return a smart pointer so that we can correctly control the lifespan of the object without worrying to much:

```
    virtual std::unique_ptr<CBaseDecorator> __Clone(CParticleInstance* pFirstInstance, CParticleInstance* pInstance)
    {
        return std::make_unique<CTimeEventDecorator>(*this, pFirstInstance, pInstance);
    }
```

---

In modern C++ you should probably add `overrides` if this overrides a virtual function in the base class.

If your base class does not have virtual functions then you should probably have a virtual destructor for this class (or your base class).

---

I am going to say what are you trying to pull!!!!

```
            while (it_next != it_end && it_next->m_fTime <= d.fTime)
                ++it_cur, ++it_next;

                // Your using the comma operator to get multile actions
                // actions into a single statement. Even if that was a
                // a good idea (and its not) I would still tell you to
                // add braces around the sub block to make it clear.

                // But this is truly horrible.
                // A lot of developer's will not even know what you did there.
```

Be clear concise and write like the next maintainer owns an axe and knows where you live.

```
            while (it_next != it_end && it_next->m_fTime <= d.fTime)
            {
                ++it_cur;
                ++it_next;
            }
```

It will not be any less effecient spread over two lines.

---

This might have been a place to add your own types to the class:

```
    typename TTimeEventContainerType::const_iterator it_start;
    typename TTimeEventContainerType::const_iterator it_end;
    typename TTimeEventContainerType::const_iterator it_cur;
    typename TTimeEventContainerType::const_iterator it_next;
```

I would have written:

```
    using const_iterator = TTimeEventContainerType::const_iterator;
    
    const_iterator   it_start;
    ...
```

---

I hope that is not an owned pointer.

```
    T* pData;
```

Otherwise your compiler generated copy and assignment operators are not going to work as expected. Which is another reason to wrap pointers. To make their use clear. As a maintainer I now have to go and find out if you are accidentally leaking pointers.

```
    using NowOwnedRawPointer = T*;
    NowOwnedRawPointer  pData;
```